# Run individual windows service programmatically on two different server

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service. This service is installed on two 
different servers.

Installed services are on running mode.

My client demands only one is active at any given time at a time. One service active and the latter is only there to watch over another service; if it fails or stops, the latter will start.

My concern is how can I achieve this?

I can't use socket and service controller.

I'm just looking for Load Balancing kind of thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the Idea you may implement.

`WMI` can get running process on remote system. Also the `Process.GetProcess` method here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx. Before that you need to configuire the remote system to be accessed.

After the all the configuration over call the any of the above mentioned method using timer. If the particular process not running you can start remotly.

Comment: Thanks Vijay for your response. I cant go with methods because of privileges issues. Is there another way to do this things???